Using Masquerade with ruby on rails
I have ROR application on 3 layers. Admin > Centre > Branch
I am using masquerade to switching users.

Admin can switch to Center and then Switch to Branch
Admin can directly switch to Branch
Centre can switch to Branch

On switching from Admin I am using
<%= link_to 'Switch User', masquerade_path(center), title: 'Switch User' %>
And for returning back
def after_back_masquerade_path_for(resource)
  admin_active_centers_path
  centre_dashboard_path if resource.center?
end

And it's working fine till here. My issue is when i am going to center and then going to branch from admin. and returning it's trying to returning back to admin directly while it should return back to center and in after_back_masquerade_path_for method resource is also admin not center while it should be center user.
How do i manage that on returning back it should return where it's comes from
